# UK visa application query

Tags: visas, uk, terminology

I have applied for UK visa with 6 people.

All got visa and I got Entry Clearance.

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an [immigration advisor in the UK](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-visa-and-an-entry-clearance-in-the-UK):

> It depends who you are talking to.
>
> Entry clearance means the sticker in a passport granting someone
>   permission to come to the UK for a specific purpose.
>
> Technically a visa is entry clearance for a visa national. A visa
>   national is someone travelling on one of the passports listed in
>   Appendix 2 of [Immigration Rules Appendix V: visitor
>   rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).
>   Entry clearance for a non-visa national is just called entry
>   clearance.
>
> However is common daily speech, “visa” is used to mean all kind of
>   permission to be in the UK, including an actual visa as defined above,
>   entry clearance in general, a residence permit showing leave to
>   remain, or leave to enter granted on a stamp for a non-visa national
>   visitor.